# Automated Unit Testing Oracle BPEL SOA projects

Tags: unit-testing, soa, bpel, oracle-fusion-middleware

Is there an alternative to the Oracle SCA Unit tests provided with JDeveloper for testing SOA projects/BPEL?

The problem I have is with it is the amount of effort required to write the tests through the clunky UI and the smallest change will invalidate all tests currently built which makes them un-maintainable.

The other issue is due to the graphical interface the SOA composite must first be written before unit tests can be written meaning a test driven-development is not possible.

The final issue is the emulation functionality is incomplete with database partner links.

Answer (score 2):

I use SOAP-UI to perform unit testing.  I create separate test scripts with SOAP-UI which allow me to generate a number of different test case scenarios which can be targeted at individual services.

I then invoke these from a Jenkins/Hudson script to provide continuous integration testing.

In this way you can do your TDD without first creating the composite.

With your database partner links you can emulate them either with a stub composite or alternatively with SOAPUI.  This depends on what your configuration is and exactly what you use the data for.